# cant overlay mask without the color changing?

Tags: python, image, opencv

From the below image I have created below mask with the following code:

```
 hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
 mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_color, upper_color)
 res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= mask)
```

Image:

[image: Here is the input image]

The mask:

[image: mask]

I want to overlay res that looks like this:

[image: res]

I use this below code to overlay it.

```
bgra = cv2.addWeighted(bgra, 1, res, 1, 0)
```

in a loop that changes the color of the original image

```
for i in tqdm((range(rang)), ascii=True, desc = 'Loops'):
        hmod += speed
        alpha = img[:, :, 3]

        bgr = img[:, :, 0:3]

        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

        h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)

        hnew = np.mod(h + hmod, 180).astype(np.uint8)

        hsv_new = cv2.merge([hnew, s, v])

        bgr_new = cv2.cvtColor(hsv_new, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

        bgra = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_new, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
        bgra[:, :, 3] = alpha
        if maskPresent[-1]:
            bgra = cv2.addWeighted(bgra, 1, res, 1, 0)
        if i == 0:
            chromas = bgra
        else:
            try:
                chromas = cv2.vconcat([bgra, chromas])
            except MemoryError:
                raise MemoryError('Out of memory(Try using an image with a lesser resolution or use  a higher speed)')
```

but this also changes the color of the mask when the image is concatenated even though the res variable stays constant. Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: Please provide your input image for img

Answer (score 0):

````
chromares = cv2.bitwise_and(bgra, bgra, mask= mask)
bgra -= chromares
bgra += originalres #what was res```
````